# liliypond NIL NULL NOOP symbol – or how to define a empty expression

Tags: scheme, guile, lilypond, no-op

**tl;dr** How to define a noop expression in lilypond?

Hello, I play the organ and sometimes need to transcribe some sheet music for it. I use lilypond for this.

For pedaling symbols I defined some shortcuts like these:

```
lt = -\tweak direction #DOWN \rtoe
lh = \lheel
rt = \rtoe
rh = -\tweak direction #UP \lheel
```

```
c4\lt
```

One reason is that I'm used to slightly other kind of notation than the default, the other is just to make it shorter to write.

A 3rd benefit of this is, that I could disable this by redefining it to empty symbols. 
This would be great, because I usually do several different format editions from the same music by using `include "..."`. E.g. on sheet music with 3 staffs (man I, man II, pedal) there is enough space for pedaling symbols, but on a combined 2 staff sheet (man I, man II + pedal) there is not.

Currently I use the empty chord as the empty expression in these cases like this:

```
lt = <>
lh = <>
rt = <>
rh = <>

\include "includes/music.ily"

\score { … }
```

But this seams not to be exactly noop, because it has side effects if combined with other accents like `\staccato`.

```
c4\lt\staccato
```

**Does anyone know how to define a really neutral expression in lilypond?**